# Data type mismatch in criteria expression delphi

Tags: database, delphi, types, mismatch

I get an error message when using ADOQuery. My Error Message:

> data type mismatch in criteria expression.

This my code

```
 CtkTransJual2.adoQuery1.close;
 CtkTransJual2.adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('vTgl1').Value:=TglAwal.date;
 CtkTransJual2.adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('vTgl2').Value:=TglAkhir.date+1;
 CtkTransJual2.adoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('kodeCustomer').Value:=combobox2.Text;
 CtkTransJual2.adoQuery1.Open;
```

I have also changed parameter properties DataType for kodeCustomer from ftString to ftWordString,  but still not working

Comment: What is the type of the `kodeCustomer` column ? Is that an integer type ? If so, you need to assign to its `Value` an integer (`combobox2.Text` is a string).

Comment: It's difficult to say where the mismatch is, because you didn't tell us anything about the columns in the DB. We can't see them from where we sit. If you want us to solve a data type mismatch, you first have to give us the details about the data types.

Comment: What @TLama said.  Also: "I have also change paramter properties DataType for kodeCustomer"  From what and to what?  These and the kodeCustomer column type are important, so your q should include this info.

Comment: iam change the type from KodeCustomer is ftStirng to ftWordString, i am not sure if this is sure

Comment: Fine, but you still haven't said what the KodeCustomer column type is (in the database, I mean), despite KenW and I both asking.  Do you not think you need to check that the *column* type matches the parameter type?

Comment: We don't even know what type of database engine OP is using.

Comment: i use ms access anda type of KodeCustomer in msaccess is Text

Comment: Thanks, add those bits of information to your question and I'll retract my close vote :-)

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to pass a `TDate` value to the fields of type `DATETIME` in your DB, the first two params. cause this problem, because they become to be the type `ftFloat` instead of `ftDateTime`. If you pass a `TDate` value to the `Value` variant, it becomes `varDouble` type and that type is mapped (in the `VarTypeToDataType` function) to `ftFloat`. Either cast there to `TDateTime`, like e.g. `...Value := TDateTime(TglAwal.date);`, or explicitly set those parameter types to `ftDateTime`.

Comment: i try to dataType propertis for TglAwal & TglAkhir from ftWordString to ftDateTime and its work. thank u very much

Comment: This is why I hate using the `Value` property. Implicit conversions are sometimes wrong.  Better to use the `As...` properties instead, eg: `ParamByName('vTgl1').AsDate:=TglAwal.date;` `ParamByName('vTgl2').AsDate:=TglAkhir.date+1;` `ParamByName('kodeCustomer').AsString:=combobox2.Text;`

Comment: @Remy, that's right, unfortunately for ADO's [`TParameter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TParameter_Properties) it's still the only way.

Comment: @TLama: You are right, the `As...` properties apply to `TParam`, not ADO's `TParameter`. In that case, you should set the [`TParameter.DataType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TParameter.DataType) property before setting the `TParameter.Value` property, eg: `ParamByName('vTgl1').DataType := ftDate; ParamByName('vTgl1').Value := TglAwal.date;`

Comment: @Remy, yup, that's what OP finally did to resolve this problem (I mentioned it as *"or explicitly set those parameter types to ftDateTime"* as OP is obviously aware of `DataType` property).